# Problem running a script after resume

Tags: scripts, suspend

I am trying to run a script after resuming from suspend. I need this script to disable the right click in the touchpad and to fix a problem of my wifi. Accordingly to [How to run script after resume and after unlocking screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204073/how-to-run-script-after-resume-and-after-unlocking-screen) I placed a script called autorun.sh in /etc/pm/sleep.d:

```
#! /bin/bash 
case "$1" in
hibernate|suspend)
    sudo -u giorgio env DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info synclient TapButton2=0
    sudo -u giorgio env DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1
    exit
    ;;
thaw|resume)
    sudo -u giorgio env DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info synclient TapButton2=0
    sudo -u giorgio env DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1
exit
;;
esac
exit
```

The problem is that when I resume, I realize that the script didn't actually work (the right click is not disabled) and in the log file /var/log/pm-suspend.log I have this lines:

```
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/autorun.sh resume suspend:

(process:15304): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(process:15310): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

What I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of the commands you have there, can you troubleshoot with `touch /tmp/resumed_okay` or something similar? Also, presumably the commands run fine if you run them manually from the command line? (Also, you don't need the `exit`s in the script.)

Comment: Yes, the script runs fine from the command line.

Comment: Good, so now try running dummy actions with `touch /tmp/resumed_okay` in your autorun script. Is the file created on resume?

Comment: Added this line: `sudo -u giorgio env DISPLAY=:0 zenity touch /tmp/resumed_okay` No file was created on resume

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was unclear. Use just the line `touch /tmp/resumed_okay` without anything else.

Comment: Ok, I added 'touch /tmp/resumed_okay' before the first exit of the original script. In this case, the file was created. The problem is due to the fact that I want to run the commands as su I guess..

Comment: Okay good, so now we know that the resume script is being triggered at least. I don't quite understand what the commands you are trying to run are, though. `zenity` is for creating dialogue boxes, right? So it seems like your commands are to create a dialogue box but not do anything else?

Comment: Ok, I understand I made a mess. What I want to do is to execute the lines 'synclient TapButton2=0' and 'modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1' automatically at resume from suspend. Any idea how to change the script to achieve that?

Comment: Ah, I just checked the link you gave. There they used `zenity` to display the dialogue box just as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend|thaw|resume)
        export DISPLAY=:0.0
        sudo -u giorgio synclient TapButton2=0
        sudo -u giorgio modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1
        ;;
esac
```

A few things.

- You had two branches to your `case` statement, but they both did the same thing, so I shortened it to a single branch. I don't think that you can have anything other than `hibernate|suspend|thaw|resume`, but just in case, I left it there.
- As per my comments, you don't need `exit`.
- I'm not 100% sure what `env DISPLAY=:0` does, but I replaced it with something that I know works (and is more concise).
- As per my comments, `zenity` is for creating dialogue boxes, so I think you must have gotten a bit confused somewhere.

Comment: I think this solution is correct. However, when the laptop finish the resume the effect of 'synclient TapButton2=0' is disappeared, that is, the value of TapButton2 is 3 again. I think when resuming, it runs a script after running my autorun, that recover the old value of TapButton. Is it possible to make it run autorun.sh in the last place?

Comment: I solved renaming autorun.sh as 00-zrun.sh. Now it runs it at the very end of the resume process and the action is permanent.

Comment: Nice find (and a +1 for it too :-). Glad I could help!