# How can I open a browser tab after resuming from sleep?

Tags: command-line, bash, google-chrome, suspend

I've bashed around on this one for awhile, no pun intended. I just want to open my todo list url in my browser every time my computer wakes from suspend. The command to do this normally is easy:

```
xdg-open https://complice.co/
```

...but that doesn't work, because "Please start Google Chrome as a normal user." Same if I try `sensible-browser`.

So then I try

```
sudo -H -u malcolm bash -c 'sensible-browser "https://complice.co/" >> "$LOGFILE"'
```

...and this totally works if I'm just in a terminal as root, but if I try to put it in a `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` script, then it fails silently. I tried

```
sudo -H -u malcolm bash -c 'sleep 10; sensible-browser "https://complice.co/" >> "$LOGFILE"'
```

...but it seems that the process is killed before sleep 10 finishes. (Based on trying `sleep 10; echo "WAT" >> "$LOGFILE";`)

This feels like it should be simple, but I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Here's some reading material: [one](http://askubuntu.com/a/226284/295286), [two](http://askubuntu.com/q/204073/295286), [three](http://askubuntu.com/a/92235/295286)

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to place this script bellow into `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` call it `70resumescript.sh`, and give it executable permissions with `sudo chmod +x scriptname.sh`. In addition, I wrote the script with `sudo nano scriptname.sh` so that the script will be owned by root. So the script must have +x permission and be owned by root. Feel free to modify the scrip to suit your needs

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    resume|thaw)
        # date >> /home/serg/LOG
        # echo "Script runs" >> /home/serg/LOG
        DISPLAY=:0 ; export DISPLAY
        sleep 4
        su serg -c 'firefox google.com'
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: If you like my answer, give me an upvote. Solved your problem ? Click the grey check-mark to accept my answer